# How to use Route Constraint and Attribute Routing together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, attributerouting, route-constraint

I use Route Constraint in my website and Now I need to use Attribute Routing.

Route Constraint class:

```
public class BusConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        private RouteDB routeDb = new RouteDB();


        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (values[parameterName] != null)
            {
                var permalink = values[parameterName].ToString();

                try
                {
                    List<AdakDbConnect.RouteTable> routeTables;
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["RouteTables"] == null)
                    {
                        routeTables = routeDb.GetRouteTables(AdakDbDll.Username, AdakDbDll.Password);
                        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("RouteTables", routeTables, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(45), TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        routeTables = HttpContext.Current.Cache["RouteTables"] as List<AdakDbConnect.RouteTable>;
                    }
                    RouteTable Route = routeTables?.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Link == permalink && p.Controlller == "Bus");
                    if (Route != null)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception)
                {

                }


                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

For Attribute Routing use this code above action :

```
[Route("Bus")]
[Route("Bus/index")]
[Route("Bus/{From:int}/{To:int}/{Date:int}/{IsForeign:int:range(0,1)}/{Title}")]
```

Once of  Attribute Routing and Route Constraint worked currently alone. But when I use together such as this case Attribute Routing worked Only and Route Constrain don't work.

RouteConfig :

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

                //---------------------BusRoute---------------------------
                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BusRoute",
                url: "{*permalink}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Bus", action = "Index" },
                constraints: new { permalink = new BusConstraint() },
                namespaces: new[] { "TravelEnterProject.Controllers" }
                );
}
```

How can I use Route Constraint and Attribute Routing together?

Comment: You need to create a custom attribute - refer [this article](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-2-attribute-routing-with-custom-constraints) for an example

Comment: One of my url's is "  /Bus-Ticket  "  Now If I delete Attribute Routing this work currently or If add Attribute Routing such as [Route("Bus-Ticket")] work currently. Now how to create custom attribute routing? can you post a code?

Answer (score 0):

Routing will be work as you defined in RouteConfig File sequentially.

as per your RouteConfig.cs file

you defined routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); --> for attribute routing
and then you defined Conventional routing.

So if you used both the routing in your controller then only attribute routing will be work.

If you want to work as per conventional routing then change the sequence of def.

first define conventional routing  routes.MapRoute()
then routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();